# Using SqlQuery in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is this really true that order of sql parameters in sql stored procedure must match the order of sql parameters used in SqlSquery:

```
 var Parameter = new List<SqlParameter>();
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParamOne", 1));
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParamTwo", 2));
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParamThree", 3));

context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("exec sp_Stored_Procedure @ParamOne, @ParamTwo, @ParamThree", Parameter.ToArray()).ToList<myEntityType>();
```

And in case sql developer decides to change stored procedure in the following way

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Stored_Procedure]
@ParamOne as int,
@ParamTwo as int,
@ParamThree as int, 

AS ......
```

the result set will be empty?

This could raise many issues and I am asking is there something I am missing in this scenario?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s I agree. I was just using it as a default stored procedure name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was oblivious to the situation at first!

Something like this should resolve your issue:

```
 var Parameter = new List<SqlParameter>();
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", 1));
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", 2));
 Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@p3", 3));

context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("exec sp_Stored_Procedure @ParamOne = @p1, @ParamTwo = @p2, @ParamThree = @p3", Parameter.ToArray()).ToList<myEntityType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could actually work BOTH ways.

If you have a query:

```
"exec sp_Stored_Procedure @p0, @p1, @p2"
```

Your parameters array will be assigned in order.

However if you have a query:

```
"exec sp_Stored_Procedure @username, @password"
```

Use an array of SqlParameter e.g. new SqlParameter("@password", userSuppliedPassword) then order is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no real difference between these two beside param name.

Comment: This article describes the variation in the parameters a little better: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I have changed my code so you can better understand the problem

Comment: Oh i see what you're suggesting.  I'll update my answer with a workaround.